# Google reCaptcha 2.0 Json Validation stop working

Tags: php, json, recaptcha

I'm getting a problem that Google reCaptcha 2.0 validation refuse to received the results anymore. No changes as been made. Has suddenly stopped to work.

I have another customer who i build the same PHP Form, and still worked well. Don't know what happen.

See my Form code :

```
<form method="post" action="envoi_appel_de_service.php">                
        <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#337ab7 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-building"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Informations sur l'adresse du service</p>

              <!-- Nom de la compagnie -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nom_compagnie" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Nom de la compagnie <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom_compagnie" placeholder="Le nom de l'entreprise" required>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Adresse -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="adresse" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Adresse <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adresse" placeholder="Adresse de l'entreprise" required>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Ville -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="ville" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Ville <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ville" placeholder="Le nom de la ville de l'entreprise" required>
                    </div>
              </div>

             <!-- Province -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="province" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;" name="province">Province <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select name="province" class="form-control">
                          <option value="Alberta">Alberta</option>
                          <option value="Colombie-Britanique">Colombie-Britanique</option>
                          <option value="Ile-du-Prince-Edouard">Ile-du-Prince-Edouard</option>
                          <option value="Manitoba">Manitoba</option>
                          <option value="Nouveau-Brunswick">Nouveau-Brunswick</option>
                          <option value="Nouvelle-Ecosse">Nouvelle-Ecosse</option>
                          <option value="Nunavut">Nunavut</option>
                          <option value="Ontario">Ontario</option>
                          <option selected="selected" value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
                          <option value="Saskatchewan">Saskatchewan</option>
                          <option value="Terre-Neuve-Labrador">Terre-Neuve-Labrador</option>
                          <option value="Territoires du Nord-Ouest">Territoires du Nord-Ouest</option>
                          <option value="Yukon">Yukon</option>
                          </select>
                     </div>
              </div>

                <!-- Code postale -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="code_postale" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Code postal <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code_postale" placeholder="XXX XXX" required>
                    </div>
              </div>

               <!-- Nom de la personne ressource -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="nom_responsable" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Nom du responsable <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom_responsable" placeholder="Nom de la personne &agrave; contacter" required>
                    </div>
              </div>

               <!-- Telephone -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" placeholder="X XXX XXX-XXX ext XXXX" required>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Adresse courriel -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="courriel" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Adresse courriel <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="courriel" placeholder="Adresse courriel valide" required>
                    </div>
              </div>


            <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#A41313 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-print"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Informations sur le produit</p>

             <!-- Marque -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="marque" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Marque</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marque" placeholder="Marque du produit">
                    </div>
              </div>

                 <!-- ModÃƒÂ¨le -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="numero_modele" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Num&eacute;ro de mod&egrave;le</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numero_modele" placeholder="Veuillez inscrire le num&eacute;ro de mod&egrave;le">
                    </div>
              </div>

                <!-- Garantie -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="garantie" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Garantie</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="garantie" placeholder="Est-ce que le produit est sous garantie?">
                    </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Description du problÃƒÂ¨me -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="description" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Description du probl&ecirc;me</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="description"></textarea>
                    </div>
              </div>

              <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#337ab7 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Pr&eacute;f&eacute;rences pour le rendez-vous</p>

              <!-- DisponibilitÃƒÂ© -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="disponibilite" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Disponibilit&eacute;</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="disponibilite" placeholder="Quel est le meilleur moment pour vous joindre?">
                    </div>
              </div>

              <!-- CoordonnÃƒÂ©es -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="coordonnees" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="font-size:16px; line-height:16px; padding-top:10px;">Coordonn&eacute;es</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="coordonnees" placeholder="Optionnel">
                    </div>
              </div>

                <p class="bg-primary lead" style="padding-top:7px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:7px; background-color:#A41313 !important;">&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lock"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;S&eacute;curit&eacute; antipourriel</p>

              <!-- Validation reCaptcha franco Google -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="input12" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right" style="padding-top:28px !important;">S&eacute;curit&eacute; antipourriel <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i><sup></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="*****"></div>
                          </div>    
                    </div>

              <!-- Soumettre -->
              <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="submit" class="col-sm-4 form-control-label text-right">&nbsp;</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                         <button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Soumettre</button>
                    </div>
              </div>
                     <br />
                                    <p class="text-center" style="margin-bottom: 0px !important;">
                                    Les champs dot&eacute;s de <sup><i class="fa fa-asterisk" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:10px !important;"></i></sup> sont obligatoires !</p>

              </form>
</div>

</div>
                    </div>
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

        $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
        $privatekey = "*****";

        $response = file_get_contents($url."?secret=".$privatekey."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $data = json_decode($response);

        if(isset($data->success) AND $data->success==true){

            $to = "email@email.com";
            $from = $_POST['courriel'];
            $from_name = $_POST['nom_responsable'];
            $subject = "Reception d'un appel de service ";
            $nom_compagnie = $_POST['nom_compagnie'];
            $adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
            $ville = $_POST['ville'];
            $province = $_POST['province'];
            $code_postale = $_POST['code_postale'];
            $nom_responsable = $_POST['nom_responsable'];
            $courriel = $_POST['courriel'];
            $telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
            $marque = $_POST['marque'];
            $numero_modele = $_POST['numero_modele'];
            $garantie = $_POST['garantie'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];              
            $disponibilite = $_POST['disponibilite'];
            $coordonnees = $_POST['coordonnees'];

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-to: $courriel";

            $message = "
             <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Appel de service  (rempli sur le site internet)</title>
            <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">
            <style type=\"text/css\">
            h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
                font-family: Cambria, \"Hoefler Text\", \"Liberation Serif\", Times, \"Times New Roman\", serif;
                color: #272727;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h2 style=\"font-size: 1.25em; font-family: Gotham, ʼHelvetica Neueʼ, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\">Vous avez re&ccedil;u une demande d'appel de service en ligne.</h2>
            <table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Informations sur l'adresse du service</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Nom de la compagnie</td>
                  <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$nom_compagnie</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Adresse</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$adresse</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Ville</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$ville</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Province</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$province</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Code postale</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$code_postale</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Nom du responsable</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$nom_responsable</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">T&eacute;l&eacute;phone</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$telephone</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Adresse courriel</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$courriel</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
            <table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Informations sur le produit</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Marque</td>
                  <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$marque</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Num&eacute;ro de mod&egrave;le</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$numero_modele</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Garantie</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$garantie</td>
                </tr>
                <tr bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">
                  <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">Description du probl&egrave;me :</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height=\"75\" colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"top\">$description</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <br>
            <table width=\"500\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"2\">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan=\"2\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#84BDEC\"><h3>Pr&eacute;f&eacute;rences pour le rendez-vous</h3></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width=\"155\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Disponibilit&eacute;</td>
                  <td width=\"313\" align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$disponibilite</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\" bgcolor=\"#D5D5D5\">Coordonn&eacute;es</td>
                  <td align=\"left\" valign=\"middle\">$coordonnees</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
             ";

   $resultat = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);         


            if($resultat){
                        header('Location: appel_de_service.php?CaptchaPass');

            }else{
                echo "mail could not be sent";
            }
        }else{
                    header('Location: appel_de_service.php?CaptchaFail');
        }

    }else{
        header('Location: appel_de_service.php?CaptchaError');

    }

 ?>
```

Don't have a clue why it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It's look like Google reCaptcha has some stranged issue. I've seen a lot of users has the same problem (suddently stopped to work properly). Does anyone has experience the same?

Comment: I've not been able to resolve it. It seems that Google having troubles. I change for another Captcha secrity. My customer can't really wait weeks to get replies.

Comment: Answers to similar questions are indicating that `file_get_contents()` needs to be a POST operation.

Comment: @JeromyFrench : What is the equivalent command for `file_get_contents()` but with POST method? I'm not quite good in PHP yet. I've read in docs but `file_post_contents()` not seem to working.